# Is the sequence pointwise convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

$\left(f_{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where 
$$
f_n\left(x\right) = 
\begin{cases}
n, & \text{if } x\geq n \\
1, & \text{ if } x < n
\end{cases}
$$
I need to determine whether the above is pointwise convergent. I know that this involves finding the limit but I am not sure how to go about approaching 2 cases.

Comment: Your first sentence is not a sentence. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Fix an $x_0$. Look whether $\bigl(f_n(x_0)\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually have to deal with two cases here. Pick any $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $N > y$, then $\forall n > N$, $f_n(y) = 1$.

This tells us that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $1$ at $y$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$